# Using D3D9 code on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows, directx, windows-phone-8.1

We have code for PC which for ages has used DX9, i.e. we call Direct3dCreate9 and go from there. It works just fine on machines with DX9 DX10 and DX11 installed.

We want to use the majority of this code for a windows phone 8.1 app. I have a sample project running on the emulator using DX11, so what is the easiest way to get our DX9 code running on the phone, assuming we don't need any DX10 or DX11 features.

I've included D3d9.h but the Direct3dCreate9 call isn't found in the D3d11.lib.

So, can we just use the D3D9.lib from the PC Direct X SDK (August 2009) and link to that ?
Or should we create a DX11 object and if we do can we then use DX9 calls on it ?
Or is it going to be painful ! ? I'm more than a little confused what's actually happening here !

Thanks

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <d3d11_1.h>` or `#include <d3d11_2.h>` if you target Windows Phone 8.1.

And port you code to DirectX 11 the call is `D3D11CreateDevice`. It will be painful!

```
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] = 
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3
};
```

You will still use this feature level.

```
// Create the Direct3D 11 API device object and a corresponding context.
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> device;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> context;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    D3D11CreateDevice(
        nullptr, // Specify nullptr to use the default adapter.
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        nullptr,
        creationFlags, // Set set debug and Direct2D compatibility flags.
        featureLevels, // List of feature levels this app can support.
        ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels),
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION, // Always set this to D3D11_SDK_VERSION.
        &device, // Returns the Direct3D device created.
        &m_featureLevel, // Returns feature level of device created.
        &context // Returns the device immediate context.
        )
    );


// Get the Direct3D 11.1 API device and context interfaces.
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    device.As(&m_d3dDevice)
    );


DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    context.As(&m_d3dContext)
    );
```

Comment: So there is no way to run DX9 code on Windows Phone 8.1 ? By including a different library ?

Comment: Yes, you can only include d3d11_2.h in Windows Phone 8.1 which is the DirectX 11.2 library.